# Slide navigation with user controls in MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, user-controls, navigation

I'm developping a MVVM application in WPF.
In my project, I have a main window and many user controls.
The main window has to be used to host the user controls.
I would like to set a system which can allow me to navigate between the different users controls with a slide effect.
The main window doesn't contain no navigation button.
All the navigations buttons are on the different users controls.
For example, I have a button (Button A) on the user control A. When I click this button, I would like to switch from user control A to user control B (with a slide effect).
The user control B has a navigation button too, the button B. When I click the button B, I would like to switch to the user control "X" ("X" is to say that it could be any user control), etc...
I would like to develop a kind of "navigation service" in which there would be a function like :

```
NavigationService.SlideTo(new UserControlX(), Directions.LeftToRight);
```

I know it would be difficult but I would like to have some ideas or suggestions in which way I have to work, while keeping the MVVM model.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Prism Region: [Prism MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648611.aspx)

1. Create a region in your main window

   ```
   <ContentControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="MainRegion" x:Name="MainRegion" />
   ```
2. Use RegionManager to navigate to different user controls on click cammand of the buttons

   ```
   var regionManager = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IRegionManager>();
   regionManager.RequestNavigate("MainRegion", "UserControlName");//good practice to use fully qualified usercontrol name like "namespace.UserControlName"
   ```
3. For sliding effect try similar like this in the user control(even can try different animation styles, this is just a sample):

   ```
   <UserControl.Triggers>
       <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Control.Loaded">
           <BeginStoryboard>
               <Storyboard >
                   <ThicknessAnimation Duration="0:0:.8" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" From="1920,0,0,0" To="0" AccelerationRatio=".1"/>
               </Storyboard>
           </BeginStoryboard>
       </EventTrigger>
   </UserControl.Triggers>
   ```

Hope it helps ...

Comment: It doesn't appear to work for .net4 (or at least one if it's dependencies don't).